# How can I select the algolia search hits and redirect it to the desired Viewcontroller?

Tags: swift, uitableview, algolia, instantsearch

So I finally figured out how to setup Algolia search in my app. It felt good for 10 seconds when the hits showed up as I typed, but then I clicked one of the cells and realized it doesn't instantiate the `TeacherDetailsViewController` like how my normal cells did.

Here is my normal tableview. [image: Tableview]

This is the VC it instantiates with each event.

[image: Event Details VC]

When I select the cell in the Algolia search, this happens ...
[image: Algolia cell]

Does anybody know how I can hook up those search result cells with the same VC I instantiate with my normal tableview cells?

Some extra code that will clarify the result cells.

```
struct NameOfEventTableViewCellConfigurator: TableViewCellConfigurable {



let model: NameOfEvent

init(model: NameOfEvent, indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.model = model
}

func configure(_ cell: UITableViewCell) {
    cell.textLabel?.text = model.eventName
    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: Constants.CellDetails.fontName, size: 25)
    
}
```

}